# How does Time To Live work in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, ttl

After reading the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content) I expected to be able to set a cache control to an amount of time and then the blob would be deleted or become unavailable. However, I've set the cache control of a blob to 60 seconds and over an hour later it's still available.

[image: Image of blob properties]

Am I missing something? Is this not how TTL should work?

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the TTL does not mean "the blob would be deleted or become unavailable", it means the cache of the blob will be expired.

And at this time(TTL expired), if the client requests the blob, it will not use the cached-blob in cdn(which is already expired). Instead, it will directly request the blob stored in `blob storage`.

Comment: So is there no automatic deletion of blobs in Azure Blob Storage based on timestamp?

Comment: @scottdavidwalker You can use [blob storage management lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal) for automatic deletion based on timestamp.

Comment: That's awesome, shame it's a minimum of a day :-\
Thanks Ivan